# Kubernetes exit code 243

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I'm facing an issue with the deployement of my Node.js application on my Kubernetes container.

The container is stuck on Crashlooping with this error "Back-off restarting failed container" and as error code i have this "Reason: Error - exit code: 243"

I did a describe of the pod i found nothing except the "Back-off restarting failed container" .
If someone could help that would be great thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the container locally?

Comment: I have no errors , i even deployed using skaffold it works , only when using the azure pipelines i have the error

Comment: I'm seeing this in Azure, too. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: The problem was i was using latest node version in my Dockerfile , so i had to define a version for node

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this worked, but it seems to be something with using `npm run...` to start the node service. I experimented with changing my Docker file to launch the container using:

`CMD npm run start`

To just running the node command, using exactly what NPM should have been running, directly:

`CMD node ...`

EDIT:

In our environment it was an access problem. To get NPM working, we had to chown all the directories:

`COPY --chown=${uid}:${gid} --from=builder /app .`

Comment: This fixed my issue too...so weird. I changed from an `npm` command to a `node` command to start my service in the Dockerfile and it works again.